# should I connect vertices on a high poly or low poly mesh?

Tags: modeling, topology, wireframe

if I am making a low poly to high poly object, does every vertex have to connect on either the high or low poly?[image]

Comment: Please provide more details. If possible reference images.

Comment: Hello, the answer is that it depends. Could you add a bit more information, and why you think this question is relevant ?

Comment: 'Connet' as in have all the vertices triangulated? And by 'to high poly' you mean you are adding a subdivision modifier?

Comment: You can connect the vertices, it doesn't always matter to have ngons or tris, it only matters if it creates artefacts

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you are going to use a subdivision mod on it then depends on the geometry. Ngons are sometimes fine but on something like a round indent the subdivision mod will mess up if you don't connect 1 in 2 of them I think.

[image]

That aside, I think you have way too much geometry in there if you are planning to use that as the low poly version. You can make a circle with just 6 or 8 vertices. (6 will require all of them to be connected for no deformation, 8 only half)

[image]

If you need more geometry for what ever reason, putting a ring of edges arround a cut will reduce the number of vertices that have to be connected for it to not deform
[image]